# how to use $this->request->param of Kohana to get request variables

Tags: php, kohana

I have written  a sample controller in kohana

```
    <?php

defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct access allowed.');

class Controller_Album extends Controller {

  public function action_index() {
    $content=$this->request->param('id','value is null');   
    $this->response->body($content);
  }

}
```

But when I am trying to hit url http://localhost/k/album?id=4
I am getting NULL value. 
how can I access request variable in kohana using request->param and without using $_GET and $_POST method ?

Comment: Why are you passing second argument `,'value is null'`?

Comment: that is option argument if value is not there . it will replace the value with that value. 
second value is default value if value not exist .

Comment: Whats your Kohana version? Use `$this->request->query('id')` if using Ko3.1

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Kohana v3.1+ Request class has `query()` and `post()` methods. They work both as getter and setter:

```
// get $_POST data
$data = $this->request->post();
// returns $_GET['foo'] or NULL if not exists
$foo = $this->request->query('foo'); 

// set $_POST['foo'] value for the executing request
$request->post('foo', 'bar');
// or put array of vars. All existing data will be deleted!
$request->query(array('foo' => 'bar'));
```

But remember that setting GET/POST data will not overload current $_GET/$_POST values. They will be sent after request executing (`$request->execute()` call).

Answer (score 4):

In Konana (3.0) you can't access $_GET/$_POST through the Request class. You'll have to directly use $_GET/$_POST

`$this->request->param('paramname', 'defaultvalue')` is for accessing params defined in the route. For route-urls like `<controller>/<action>/<id>` you would use `$this->request->param('id')` to access the  portion in the route url.

edit: in Kohana 3.1 there are `post` and `query` methods for getting/setting data of the request; check the documentation at http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/api/Request

Comment: In 3.1 Request class `has query()` and `post()` getters/setters. For example, `$request->query('var1')` returns `$_GET['var1']` value (if exists), while `$request->post('var2', 'val2')` will send `var2=val2` as POST data.

Comment: @biakaveron Can you please post your answer , as answer so that I can accept your answer

Comment: @biakaveron ah, I didn't know that (still working with ko3.0). I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Notice that altough it's more clear to use $this->request->param(), you can define action params as :

```
public function action_index($id, $seo = NULL, $something = NULL)..
```

and access those vars directly. You have to define these vars in the same order they're defined in the corresponding route (excluding the action and controller params, they're defined on request level anyways so there's no need to pass them to the action method).

EDIT: This functionality was deprecated in 3.1 and has been removed from 3.2, so it is best to avoid. You can read more here: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/upgrading#controller-action-parameters

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well, if you have not changed the default routes, you can try using the url http://localhost/k/album/4 with that controller.

As the default route is in the form: `/<controller>/<action>/<id>`

Hope it helps.